# What are the main motivations that led to coin the definition of a well ordered set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

The concept of totally ordered set is, in a sense, already rather demanding:  for a set to be totally ordered, it is required ( informally) that all its elements be  comparable.

For which reasons mathematicians went further and felt the necessity for well-ordered sets?

Is induction the main motivation?

Is the set of natural numbers the only "concrete" set that led mathematicians  to this abstraction of a well ordered set " in general"?

Comment: I would guess induction is the main reason; if you were to ask yourself "what kinds of orderings can I do strong induction over," the answer turns out to be well orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transfinite induction is important, but in order to use it you need to already have a well-ordering in hand that you want to induct along - and why would you have such a thing if you're not trying to prove a result that's a priori about well-orderings (which doesn't really count in terms of motivation)?

The key is transfinite *recursion*. The term "transfinite induction" is often used to encompass transfinite recursion as well - this is a pet peeve of mine - but they're different things: induction is a *proof technique* while recursion is a *construction method*. The idea behind transfinite recursion is that you want to build some object "step-by-step," but finitely many steps aren't going to cut it.

One obvious motivator for this is the intuitive proof of the axiom of choice: "just keep picking elements one after the other until you've built an entire choice function." Formalizing this, we run into the well-ordering principle and transfinite recursion.

Transfinite recursion also occurs outside of logic, however. For example, the **Cantor-Bendixson theorem** states that any uncountable closed set $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ can be written uniquely as the disjoint union of a perfect set and a countable set. My favorite proof uses transfinite recursion along $\omega_1$: we define a sequence of sets as

- $C_0=C$,
- $C_\lambda=\bigcap_{\alpha<\lambda}C_\alpha$ for $\lambda$ limit, and
- $C_{\alpha+1}$ is the set of limit points of $C_\alpha$.

The second-countability of $\mathbb{R}$ tells us that for some countable $\alpha$ we have $C_\alpha=C_{\alpha+1}$, and that $C\setminus C_\alpha$ is countable for every $\alpha$; meanwhile, it's easy to check that $C_\alpha=C_{\alpha+1}$ iff $C_\alpha$ is perfect. (OK fine, this only shows *existence*, but uniqueness isn't hard.)

And there are other examples as well (another one from topology: the Borel sets can be defined without recourse to transfinite recursion, but the Borel *hierarchy* - a crucial tool for analyzing Borel sets - does require it). **The point is that we often have some vague idea of building an object in stages**. This requires an appropriate notion of "sequence of stages;" thinking about what we need such a sequence to satisfy, we're led to the definition of well-orderings - we then prove transfinite induction, which is the thing which tells us that transfinite recursion works (and lets us analyze constructions by transfinite recursion).

---

As an aside, it's also worth noting that **choice plays no role in transfinite recursion per se** - the relevant axiom (scheme) is [**replacement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement). The way choice appears in arguments by transfinite recursion is by setting them up in the first place: e.g. to build a non-measurable set of reals, we start by well-ordering the reals using choice; the following transfinite recursion along that well-ordering, however, is choice-free.

Comment: +1. Just for your information, there's a proof of  Cantor-Bendixson that produces the sets directly : if I recall correctly it goes as follows;  say that $x\in C$ is [I forgot the actual name, I think it's somewhere in Bourbaki] strongly limit if any neighbourhood of $x$ $V$ has uncountable intersection with $C$. Then the set of strongly limit points of $C$ is perfect, and the complement of it is countable

Comment: @Max Oh yeah, I'd forgotten all about that one. Editing ...